# Laravel/formbuilder select option read out value with array

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent, formbuilder, laravelcollective

I'm writing a few cods around Laravel's form builder.

Here is my Controller:

```
public function create()
{
    $departments = Department::all('name');
    return view('door.project.create') ->with('departments',$departments);
}
```

On the create.blade.php, I get stuck. 
The selectbox's option would show out with JSON array, 
like:
 `{"name": "Sale"}`

And the select box codes would be down here:

```
<div class="form-group">
     {!! Form::Label('deparment_name', 'Department:') !!}
     {!! Form::select('deparment_name', $departments, null, ['mutiple' => 'multiple']) !!}
</div>
```

May I ask how do I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of:

```
$departments = Department::all('name');
```

you should use:

```
$departments = Department::pluck('name','id');
```

to get in select valid list.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It does help. Thank!